# Get hold of json content that is being sent to Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, .net-core

That's how I reach when I send some values that are specified in my input and therefore they need to send to a API.

When I try to send them to the monkey, my monkey tells me that nothing has been sent.

At my `console.log(token)`, it tells me what data is available and I also agree that it all fits together. But the problem is just that it has to come over to my API.

```
function PayStripe() {
// Open Checkout with further options:
handler.open({
    name: 'XXX ',
    description: 'XX abonnement',
    currency: "dkk",
    amount: $('#HiddenPrice').val() * 100,
    email: $('#Email').val()
});
};

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_xxxx',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function (token) {
        token.subscriptionId = $('#SubscriptionId').val();
        token.City = $('#City').val();
        token.Postnr = $('#Postnr').val();
        token.Mobil = $('#Mobil').val();
        token.Adresse = $('#Adresse').val();
        token.CVRVirksomhed = $('#CVRVirksomhed').val();
        console.log(token.subscriptionId);
        console.log(token);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/Stripe",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: token,
            success: function (data) {
                //window.location.href = '/Subscriptions/Succes';
                alert(data + "Succes")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data + "Error");
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    }
});
```

Where the problem lies is that the API is by no means able to get informed information from jquery. so it's like it can not / will receive it.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Stripe")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] JObject token)
```

When I grab the token that I need for example. then I do this here:

```
var SubscriptionId = (int)token.GetValue("subscriptionId");
```

Comment: JQuery is sending json encoded data but your controller is looking for Form Url Encoded data. And maybe try again with your translation, "monkey" is not the correct word.

Comment: You are telling ajax you are sending json but are sending uri encoded data. Need to make up your mind which way you want it

Comment: Sorry @Crowcoder i mean API.

Comment: what u mean ?? @charlietfl

Comment: Read about `contentType` in $.ajax docs

Comment: Change `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` and see what you get.

Comment: okay, if i remove `contentType: "application/json",` så giv me consol new error and say **415 (Unsupported Media Type)** @charlietfl

Comment: I have this now. @Crowcoder

Comment: NO, don't remove that, I didn't say remove that.

Comment: so if you want to send json you need to stringify it yourself and expect json in back end

Comment: okay That's how I understand what you wrote. @Crowcoder

Comment: That was really what was supposed to .. It works now !.

Do you want to answer or what you can do for a point? @charlietfl

Comment: `When I try to send them to the monkey, my monkey tells me that nothing has been sent.` - There's ya problem - Never trust a monkey ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `contentType: "application/json",` you need to stringify the data to json yourself

```
data: JSON.stringify(token),
```